# How to get iOS disk information related to reading and writing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, unix

I am looking to retrieve information regarding,

1. Percent of time spent writing to disk.
2. Percent of time spent reading from disk.

I do have the disk details such as free disk space and used disk space , but I couldn't find info regarding reading and writing.
How to obtain the information in iOS??.

```
 - (uint64_t)freeDiskspace
 {
   uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *path = [paths lastObject];//[self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:path error: &error];

   if (dictionary) {
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
} else {
    //NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error code]);
}  

return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

Comment: Apple's main tool for performance measurements is [Instruments](https://medium.com/@kazmiekr/what-every-ios-developer-should-be-doing-with-instruments-d1661eeaf64f), which is built into Xcode. That can monitor file activity, which should be a starting point for you.